# How to handle wide character data received in libcurl

Tags: c, httprequest, libcurl, deepl

I am trying to make a post request with libcurl using deepl API. I don't know how to handle the wide character data received.

There is a function like this but it can only handle char* type data.

```
size_t write_callback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    printf("%.*s", (int)realsize, (char *)contents);
    return realsize;
}
```

How can I achieve this with a function.

Comment: Why do you think you receive "wide character data", and what exactly do you mean by that? Wide characters have different size and different interpretation on different platforms. A cross-platform API cannot be stated in terms of wide characters.

Answer (score 1):

The C99 standard defines a pair of functions for conversions between wchar_t and char ("multi-byte") strings. You're looking for **wcstombs** (C99 7.20.8.2) ("wide char string to multi-byte string").

Fortunately, POSIX mirrors the C99 standard here - and unlike C standards, reading POSIX is free. See [wcstombs(3)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wcstombs.html).